# Overwriting default values in parent constructor in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, ecmascript-2020

I have an abstract Typescript class with a constructor. This constructor accepts an object and then tries to set properties of the class with the data in the object.

```
export default class AbstractModel {
    constructor(properties: object) {
        Object.assign(this, properties);
    }
}
```

Then there are several classes inheriting this `AbstractModel` class.
For example:

```
import AbstractModel from "./abstract-model";

export default class Derived extends AbstractModel {
    firstname!: string;
    lastname!: string;
    age: number = 1;
}
```

My assumption was that when I create a new `Derived` and pass `{age: 10}` in the constructor the newly created `Derived` would have `age` set to `10`. However, age always seems to be the initial value of `1`. Other properties without an initial values are being set as expected.

```
const derived = new Derived({firstname : "John", lastname: "Doe", age: 10});
```

Output:

```
Derived {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe',
  age: 1,
}
```

Logging this in the constructor of `AbstractModel` gives me the following output

```
export default class AbstractModel {
    constructor(properties: object) {
        Object.assign(this, properties);
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Derived {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe',
  age: 10,
}
```

Logging this in the constructor of `Derived` gives me the following output

```
export default class Derived extends AbstractModel {
    firstname!: string;
    lastname!: string;
    age: number = 1;

    constructor(properties: object) {
        super(properties);
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Derived {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe',
  age: 1,
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it is behaving like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial value you provide for `age` is assigned/defined¹ by your subclass constructor. That assignment/definition is done just after the call to `super` in your subclass constructor (either your explicit constructor if you provide one, or the default generated one if you don't). As a result, `age` will be `1` in your subclass, because the assignment done by the superclass constructor gets overwritten. Here's a simpler example (just using JavaScript so we can run it in Stack Snippets):

```js
class Base {
    constructor() {
        this.age = 42;
    }
}
class Derived extends Base {
    age = 1;
}

console.log(new Derived().age);
```

The generated constructor for `Derived` is:

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
}
```

..and the definition/assignment¹ setting `age` to `1` happens just after the `super(...args)` part of that.

I think the minimal-changes way to fix it in the code you've shown is to remove the default value and provide a constructor for `Derived`:

```
age: number;
constructor(obj: object) {
    super(obj);
    this.age = (obj as any).age ?? 1;
}
```

or

```
age!: number;
// ^−−− Note the "definitely assigned" assertion
constructor(obj: object) {
    super({age: 1, ...obj});
}
```

or similar ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ0PWAewHYQBcAnAV2AOyIApsAjAKwC5o76FyBKFdTXgeQbsCAOkgQAlgHNcVAgAtxEADQsGHANw8MAX1S7UAegPQ+ABwLi80AIKpQY6ABEERcQDcEAE2vQEADwIEXE8YeAgkNF4wSQRmXBIAW1oXTV4cfGIyCmpWZlYhaABeFG0uSN5MCBJTFxo1VIqMeUVRGKLoOvpoSBRohAB+OMTkolLWpH7+6ABGBp09VDs8CGwQBGEQbEkqXAQAdycXdy9rKg5xjUbGoxml-FX1ze3dg+dXD28qZD7mABYAJjGfUuGBuAMWNzMFissDs4Cgh3eXlgvgCQRCcEQ3CiMQAhEMkiktFhlplyJROnlBOR2shStirlUatRvjFmNMVMIuaxSnNoLp9OkVmsNlsdvtEcdPLAzhd1FcKjdpndhY8xS9JR8ZazYtAAUCYiDoGD-qggA)).

That said, the `AbstractModel` constructor code isn't typesafe, it'll copy over any and all own properties of the object you provide it. You may want to refactor that.

---

¹ Whether `Derived` does an assignment (effectively, `this.age = 1`) or a redefinition (`Object.defineProperty(this, "age", {value: 1, /*...*/})`) depends on the [`useDefineForClassFields`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields) configuration option. It does assignment when the option isn't enabled, and redefinition when it is. Redefinition is the way JavaScript's class fields are standardized, so the configuration option was added to TypeScript to support that newly-standard behavior when class fields were introduced to JavaScript.

Comment: That explains it then. If the assignment of the default values takes place after the call to `super`.

"That said, the AbstractModel constructor code isn't typesafe"
I know, was just trying to understand the behavior.
Seems I will need to use constructors in easy of the sub classes then.

Comment: @bleenders - Yeah, I think so. You have at least a couple of options for what the constructors look like (I've updated above), but I think you're stuck with them. :-| Happy coding!